# PHP dont write accents

Tags: php, ascii, diacritics, whatsapi

My code generates a message that I get them with file_get_contents. However, this message can be, eventually, have accents in some words, like á, ã, ç...

The PHP change this accented characters to special characters, like a ç. Ok, this not cause some problem.

However, the whatsapp dont read &cedil, for example and this message will be truncate.

How I change the codes like $ccedil; for ç in a PHP variable on by fast way?

```
$fim = file_get_contents($pedidoaux);

header("Location: http://api.whatsapp.com/send?1=pt_BR&phone=WHATSAPPNUMBER&text=$fim");
```

Answer (score 1):

URLs can only contain ASCII characters. For anything else, you need to encode them. Use `urlencode()`.

```
header("Location: http://api.whatsapp.com/send?1=pt_BR&phone=WHATSAPPNUMBER&text=" . urlencode($fim));
```

Comment: Dont works, Barmar.
With the your solution, the message are:

Pedido 20220622175325%0a%0a1 A&ccedil;&uacute;car Refinado Caravelas 1Kg %0a%0aValor total: R$4,99

Comment: `&ccedil` comes from `htmlentity()`. Why are you doing that?

Comment: I need that my code writes works like Açúcar.